# RoboCopy Log Files missing whitespace?

Tags: windows, script, robocopy

So I'm working on a script to use RoboCopy to copy a bunch of files, and log what it's copied.

It works reasonably well, except for the logfiles. They tend to look like this:

```
C:\Users\Tech\Documents\desktop.initechscan1.jpgtechscan2.jpgtechscan3.jpgtechscan4.jpgtechscan5.jpgwsus.jpgwsus2.jpgC:\Users\Tech\Documents\My Music\C:\Users\Tech\Documents\My Pictures\C:\Users\Tech\Documents\My Videos\C:\Users\Tech\Documents\My Digital Editions\
```

As you can see, the log seems to be missing all whitespace and separators between entries. Is there something I can do to fix this? It's kind of frustrating.

The commandline I'm using is this:

```
C:\Users\Tech\Desktop>Robocopy.exe C:\Users\Tech\Documents c:\Temp /e /l /b /xj /xf ntuser.* desktop.ini *.lnk /np /njh /log:migratedfiles.txt /v
```

I have the /l in there since I'm debugging, and it's the easiest way to keep from copying everything a million times.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same problem with Robocopy's log being all crammed into one line with very little readable info. What fixed it for me is something I can see in your code as well; you're running the Robocopy command from your Desktop. Try running it from say, your documents (move the bat file if you're using one, or change the directory in your command prompt if you're going straight from cmd)

I have **no** idea why, but for me this fixed the problem right up. As soon as I'd hit cd.. and moved from c:\users\ishan\desktop to cd:\users\ishan, robocopy showed a proper log again. I use a .bat file myself for the robocopy command, so I moved that one into my Documents, ran it from there, presto, problem solved.

Hope this helps your problem as well.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this same issue and believe I have found the answer.  You will have to do a small bit of searching, but after that it should be fairly easy

Search for `robo` or similar on your `C:` drive. You want to find the locations of `RoboCopy.EXE` and `RoboCopy.EXE.MUI`. On a 32 Bit Windows 7 test system that I was using, I found said files in the following directories:

```
C:\Windows\System32\RoboCopy.EXE
C:\Windows\System32\en-US\RoboCopy.EXE.MUI
```

Copy these files to a separate directory, but keep the same directory structure you find after `System32`. For example:

```
C:\Test_PGM\RoboCopy.EXE
C:\Test_PGM\en-US\RoboCopy.EXE.MUI
```

Now run `RoboCopy` from the alternate directory. For example:

```
C:\>"C:\Test_PGM\RoboCopy.EXE" "C:\Test_SRC" "C:\Test_DST" /COPYALL
```

This will provide the correctly formatted output.

Comment: THANK YOU! This was exactly the solution.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the PATH used when the batch file runs, is key.
Path variable has (for me)
%SystemRoot%\system32;
%SystemRoot%;
etc.

However a job running a bat file with:
ROBOCOPY.EXE /JOB:jobname.RCJ
runs differently to
C:\Windows\System32\ROBOCOPY.EXE /JOB:jobname.RCJ

For the job to run correctly I specify the full path in the call... I found two versions of Robocopy.exe (both identical age, product version, and do the thing properly) so I don't know what path NOT specifying a full name has a different version of the executable - but its wrong.